# tracking multiple documents with an index document in nosql DB

Tags: nosql, couchbase

I have an app where a user can create tasks with configuration (scheduling, retries etc..)
each task is given a guid and stored under this guid as a key in a nosql db (couchbase)

then I'm managing all these tasks and their status in an index docuement per account

so index looks like

```
[

    {"id":"12345-98889-0000-1111", "status":"...", ...},
    {"id":"12345-98889-0000-2222", "status":"...", ...},
    {"id":"12345-98889-0000-3333", "status":"...", ...},
    {"id":"12345-98889-0000-4444", "status":"...", ...},

]
```

every record in this json array points to a document with the full configuration of the task.

anyhow right now I have an account with and index document of 11Mb which getting pretty heavy on updating, need to get update in memory and the re-upload.

any suggestion on restructure here ? 
I was thinking using elasticsearch as the index instead of managing a big json doc but im not sure that I want to introduce another component here ...

Comment: Have you looked at using the index capabilities already built in to Couchbase? https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/learn/services-and-indexes/indexes/global-secondary-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

Any reason not to use the N1QL query language? You are already storing the documents. Create GSI indexes on whatever fields you are interested in, and use N1QL queries to access the documents. The indexes should be used intelligently for efficient access. You just need to make sure your server is running the query service.

Comment: N1QL if fairly new to us, but ill sure give it a go.